# Updating the layout using bokeh tabs

Tags: python, layout, tabs, bokeh

I am creating a dashboard for my bokeh app using a template similar to the one demonstrated here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-bokeh-in-python-part-iii-a-complete-dashboard-dc6a86aa6e23

Basically I am separating the different functions of my app into different scripts which have a function returning a Panel object containing the layout to be imported in the Tabs object defined on my main.py.

For example, this is my what my read.py script returns:

```
# First layout / plot
read_layout = bla.layout([firstColRaw,
                           secondColRaw,
                           bmo.Spacer(width=50),
                           thirdColRaw])


def read_tab():
    tab = bmo.Panel(child=read_layout, title='Read in data')
    return tab
```

This is what I have on my main.py:

```
from scripts.read import read_tab

# Tabs to select the app function
tab1 = read_tab()

nav_tabs = [tab1]
tabs = bmo.Tabs(tabs=nav_tabs, width=1500)

# Create the main layout
layout_main = bla.column(buttons,
                         tabs,
                         height=300,
                         width=1500)

# Put the tabs in the current document for display
doc.add_root(layout_main)
```

I am running into a problem when I try to update the layout of one of the tabs. In this specific example, I would like to dynamically show the user how many raw data files are being loaded in the environment.

In this specific case I modify the contents of the thirdColRaw variable which then add a div to the layout object.

If I am running the app as displayed above, I cannot update the content of the Tabs. If, on the other hand, I don't use Tabs, but instead just load the read_layout from the main.py and add it to the current doc, the layout update works just fine.

Does this mean that I cannot modify/add/remove Panel layout components dynamically? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh 0.13 this is [known layout bug](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6553). There is currently a large PR in progress to address many layout issues at once, including this one, but it will not be ready until Bokeh 1.1 is released. In the mean time, I can only suggest:

- avoiding the combination of tabs and responsive sizing modes
- using `components` to template plots into non-Bokeh layouts.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! Since I do need responsive layouts, I guess I'll need to avoid using tabs for now.